# vb.net How to get the file URL that started the program

Tags: vb.net, media-player, filenames

I am developing a media player based on the WMP Engine.

When I am setting it as a default program to open a video or audio file, then double-click at such a file, the program will open but it will not have the file loaded.

How can I get the file URL that the user double-clicked and caused my program to open?

Comment: Is this win forms?  WPF?

Comment: Yes it is win forms.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by URL but you could look at Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Comment: I don't believe you can get that information. Unless you can get that information off the file but I would think it would have to be a local file to launch your windows form. It would be no longer tied to the website.

Comment: Sorry for any misconceptions probably created by the way I typed my question - By mentioning "URL", I meant the (offline) path of the file that has been opened (double-clicked) by the user.